# Expression recursion level exceeded error in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax, arithmetic-expressions

I'm a newbie to bash scripting and trying to do some exercises. Getting error like this when I'm trying to stop the program with "finish" string.:

```
line 9: ((: finish: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "finish").
```

What is the problem?  Also I'd like to learn my other faults.
My program is:

```
#!/bin/bash
number=0
finish="finish"
temp=0
echo "Enter a number."
while true;
do
    read -r number
    if (( $number > $temp ))
    then
        temp=$number
    fi
    if [[ $number == $finish ]]
    then 
       break
    fi
done    
echo "Largest : $temp"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from [@barmar's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404927/6862601) to the related question, which talks about the same issue that @GordonDavisson mentions in his comment:

> When you use a variable in an arithmetic expression, but the value is
>   not a number, the shell treats it as another expression to evaluate.
>   So if the value is a variable name, it will get the value of that
>   variable and use it. But in this case, you have it pointing to itself.
>   So to evaluate a it has to evaluate `$finish`, and this keeps
>   repeating infinitely.

---

The simplest solution is to use a different name to your variable - say `finish_string="finish"` instead of `finish="finish"`.

Also, you can use a regex match to see if the value is numeric (note: a dollar sign is not needed to expand variables inside arithmetic expression `((...))`), then do the numeric comparison followed by the normal string comparison to see if the value is 'finish':

```
if [[ $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && ((number > temp)); then
  temp=$number
elif [[ $number == $finish ]]; then
  break
fi
```

Or, you could explicitly check if the user entered a number before doing a numeric comparison:

```
if [[ $number == $finish ]]; then
  break
else
  [[ $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Enter a valid number or 'finish' to stop"; continue; }
  if ((number > temp)); then
    temp=$number
  fi
fi
```

Run your script with `bash -x yourscript.sh` to debug it.

---

Related:

- [Expression recursion level exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30404863/6862601)

See also:

- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188199/6862601)

Comment: More specifically: the original problem was that when it sees `$number` inside the arithmetic expression, it expands it to the value of the variable: "finish". That's not a number, so it does what it always does with non-numbers in an expression: assumes they're inplicitly-referenced variables and expands them. In this case, expanding `finish` as a variable yields "finish", which isn't a number either, so it tries to expand it as a variable... etc etc etc until it decides it's tried long enough and gives up.

Comment: Amazing explanation @GordonDavisson.  I wasn't aware of this issue.

Comment: @codeforester Thanks for the answer, I got the idea. However in the 1st solution, the temp variable does not change after I assign an integer to number variable. The solution that program gives always 0, in the 2nd solution it gives the same error with mine.

Comment: My regex pattern was wrong and that's the reason the code didn't do what it was supposed to do.  I have fixed the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

"finish" is not a number but you are comparing it with a number.To solve your immediate problem, check for "finish" before doing the comparison:

```
while true;
do
    read -r number
    if [[ $number == $finish ]] ## this line moved up
    then 
       break
    fi
    if (( $number > $temp ))
    then
        temp=$number
    fi
done
```

Of course, you still have the problem that even if $number != "finish", it might still not be a number, but that was not the question...

Comment: This will work well, though not very elegant.  Arithmetic expression evaluates to false if the variables used inside `((...))` expand to non-numeric values.

Comment: @codeforester your're correct, of course. However, not checking for input validity, appears to be a different bug than the one the question was about. Addressing that issue, we might end up writing his code for him...